# Since installing XP SP2 I can no longer access my IIS hosted web pages

Tags: iis

I had a base Windows XP with IIS hosting some websites and it has been working for years, yesturday I upgraded to SP2 (which includes the security suit) because I needed .NET 3.5 and since then no one can access the web pages anymore.

When I connect to the macine locally and try to access the webpage it prompted me for a username / password - when I entered it I was able to access the page locally.

However, remotely I always get "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"... Anyone know what I need to do so that we can access the pages again?

Thanks,

Comment: Looks like it is the WINDOWS FIREWALL, when disabled it works again ... So I need to add something special to my windows firewall settings?

Comment: And while you're at it, update again to SP3.

Comment: I had to add another comment. Did you REALLY have a sub-SP XP install, facing the internet?

Comment: LOL - was an old server we kind of forgot about it ... it is not facing the net, it is intranet only.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Firewall is blocking inbound connections to IIS. You need to add an exception.

See here;

[Web server functionality may not work correctly after you install Windows XP Service Pack 2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/883607)